# javascript condition contains for conditionalpanel in shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I'm working on a Shiny app and want to add a tabpanel if a condition is TRUE. I'm using conditionalpanel function and the condition to be tested is whether or not "products" from ui input contains "C".

From the first tab, if C is clicked the "second tab" is not shown.

I think the issue is the JS condition inside the conditionalpanel.

If you have any working solution (not necessarily based on conditionalpanel) I'll appreciate your help and support.
Luigi

Here below my reprex

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(reprex)

tab_input <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Value boxes", disable = TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(
        checkboxGroupButtons(
          inputId = "products", label = tags$h1("Select products"), 
          choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
          checkIcon = list(yes = icon("ok", lib = "glyphicon"), no = icon("remove", lib = "glyphicon"))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


ui <- navbarPage("my APP", 
                 tabPanel("first tab",
                          tab_input),
                 
                          conditionalPanel(
                            condition = "input.products.contains('C')",
                            tabPanel("second_tab",
                            dashboardPage(
                              dashboardHeader(title = "Value boxes", disable = TRUE),
                              dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
                              dashboardBody(
                                
                              )
                              )
                            )
                          )
                 )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is the `conditionalPanel`? I'm not sure if you can mix the `navbarPage` and `dashboardPage` like this, e.g. the title "Value boxes" is not shown.

Comment: I've already used navbarPage and dashboardPage and it worked

Comment: @starja you have any alternative?

Comment: Unfortunately not; if I come across something I'll let you know! In my experience it's a bit of a hassle to mix the both types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
condition = "input.products.indexOf('C') > -1"
```

Comment: great! `indexOf `met the condition but the second tabpanel is shown inside the first panel and not beside it